# Excel formula - sometimes array formula, sometimes not

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I want to write some data to an Excel file, and I want the first page to show a summary of the data that are spread all over the sheets. The individual data items on a sheet can be included or excluded, and I want the summary to be calculated only on the included values.

Thus, I thought I'd use a formula like this to show, for example, an average (for which empty fields shouldn't be counted, either):

```
=AVERAGE(IF('dataSheet1'!$B:$B=1,IF('dataSheet1'!$I:$I<>"",'dataSheet1'!$I:$I,""),""))
```

If I have this formula in `dataSheet1`, everything works fine. If I have this formula in the `summary` sheet, I need to enter it as an array formula, and I have to specify the exact ranges to make it work. Is there a way (aside from adding the average in `dataSheet`, and then referencing the result in `summary`) to make the formula work without having it turn into an array formula?

Answer (score 0):

`Average` already does excludes empty values.  Thats why you can take the average of `I:I` and not get almost 0 (because its mostly empties), but to include your `B:B` check you can do something like this:

```
=SUMIF(dataSheet1!B:B,1,dataSheet1!I:I)/COUNTIF(dataSheet1!B:B,1)
```

Comment: thanks for the heads-up about `AVERAGE`. I had been using `SUMIF` and `COUNTIF` before, but these do include empties in my hands, so your solution won't work for me.